# jQuery AJAX loop doesn't finish before 'done'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a photo gallery that can be updated via an looped ajax call. The problem is, it only updates about 6 images before the "done" gets fired and the page changes. How can I make the script wait until the entire loop is finished before it executes 'done'?

```
$('#selectAlbum').change(function() {
  var thisAlbID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
  var thisAlbURL = $(this).val();
  $('.medSelectHighlight').each(function() {
     jQuery.ajax({
       url:'system/move-media.php',
       data:{photo_id:$(this).attr('id'),album_id:thisAlbID},
       dataType: 'json',
       type:'POST'
    }).done(function() {
       document.location.href='../media/'+thisAlbURL;
    });
}); 

});
```

I should also add that I have tried `async false` and it worked - however I have read that it should be avoided...

Comment: when you say loop, you mean, that `each` function right?

Comment: Yes, sorry - the jQuery .each

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're `done` executes each time an ajax is fired. Is your `done` correctly placed? I mean, it should be at the end of `each`'s closing bracket instead, should it not? Try this:

```
$('.medSelectHighlight').each(function() 
  {
        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            url:'system/move-media.php',
            data:{photo_id:$(this).attr('id'),album_id:thisAlbID},
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'POST'
         });
   }).done(function() 
         {
               document.location.href='../media/'+thisAlbURL;
         });
```

Comment: You're welcome. Seems like being async is not really an issue.

Comment: Actually - sorry to say that that solution didn't work. I hadn't uploaded the correct file when I tested it. I applied that solution and it failed. Back to square one...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of DPP, I ended up using `ajaxStop` and it worked like a charm. Code is below for those having the same issue...

```
$('#selectAlbum').change(function() {
  $('body').css('cursor', 'progress');
  var thisAlbID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
  var thisAlbURL = $(this).val();
     $('.medSelectHighlight').each(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:'system/move-media.php',
        data:{photo_id:$(this).attr('id'),album_id:thisAlbID},
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'POST'
        });
     }).ajaxStop(function() {
     document.location.href='media/'+thisAlbURL;
     });

});
```